# Gather data from loosely coupled classes

Tags: c++

In a software project, I've done my best to make the classes loosely coupled. Now I'm struggling to get the scattered data (from objects of the loosely coupled classes) into a data object. This data object (e.g. for logging) is predefined and has to be filled with data from objects of several classes. 
As the real code is proprietary, I've written the code below which should illustrate my problem:

```
class Gear {
public:
    Gear(unsigned int amount);
    ~Gear();

    void shiftUp();
    void shiftDown();

private:
    const unsigned int amount;
    unsigned int current;
};

class Speedometer {
public:
    Speedometer();
    ~Speedometer();

    void display() const;

private:
    double currentSpeed;
};

class Bike {
public:
    Bike(unsigned int nrWheels, Gear& gear, Speedometer& speedometer);
    ~Bike();

    void peddle() const;
    void break() const;

private:
    const unsigned int nrWheels;
    Gear& gear
    Speedometer& speedometer;
};

class Cyclist {
public:
    Cyclist(const std::string name, Bike& bike);
    ~Cyclist();

    void ride();

private:
    const std::string name;
    Bike& bike;
};

class Factory {
public:
    Factory();
    ~Factory();

    Cyclist& build() const;
};

struct PredefinedData {
    PredefinedData();
    ~PredefinedData();

    std::string cyclistName;
    unsigned int nrWheels;
    unsigned int currentGear;
    double currentSpeed;
};
```

A Factory (object) builds a Cyclist (object) with all objects that it references (recursively). The state of all these objects will change during the execution of the program. In order to e.g. log the state of a Cyclist object with all its references, an object from the PredefinedData class is used. This object has to be filled with data from Cyclist and its references.

Some thoughts/tests of my own:

- I've tried giving every class a reference of the PredefinedData object, but that meant that private data of objects would be known by other objects.
- I've tried a Filler object that provides functions to fill the PredefinedData object, but it feels like duplicating the PredefinedData class.
- I've also considered inheriting a class from several classes to be able to give every class access to just the data it should have access to/fill.

How would you solve this? Is there a design pattern for this situation?

Comment: Question is not clear to me. You would have data objects if you had instances of these classes. Apparently you then want to do something that is not clear from your question.

Comment: If you want your cyclist parts to log their data to a PredefinedObject, why not equip these parts with a `LogData(PredefinedObject&)` method, and call it?

Comment: I see this as a variation of my first option, with the same disadvantages:
The Gear object, which only has to fill currentGear, then has access to the cyclist' name (which is private) through the cyclistName member of PredefinedObject.
Who would call the logDat(PredefinedObject&) function? I guess Cyclist and then pass it downstream. But some field have to be updated only once, e.g. nrWheels, whereas others change continuously.

Comment: It is not clear why owning a separate instance of an object and using whatever object is passed to you look the same. They are very different things and rarely both make sense at the same time. (If you want to reply to a specific comment, mention its author like this: @MartijnPot otherwise that person will miss your reply).

Comment: @n.m. I meant 'a reference of the PredefinedData object' in my first thought/test. I changed the question accordingly. I'm still strugling to see how the logData(PredefinedObject&) function would be helpfull.

Comment: I see what is your concern. This PredefinedData thing is built in such a way that it collects and exposes private data from several different classes. You need to either change it so that it does not expose stuff other classes are not meant to see, or hide it and wrap it in some other class that does not expose things. I don't see how it's possible to keep the existing PredefinedObject interface and isolate sensitive data from each other. No miracle solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
class Cyclist {
public:
    Cyclist(const std::string name, Bike& bike)
      : data(name), bike(bike) {}

    const PredefinedData& getPredefinedData()
    {
        data.nrWheels = bike.getNrWheels();
        data.currentGear = bike.gear.getCurrent();
        data.currentSpeed = bike.speedometer.getSpeed();
        return data;
    }

private:
    PredefinedData data; // includes name, used as a cache
    Bike& bike;
};
```

Comment: This works if gear and speedometer are public, which is not what I would like (breaks 'information hiding'). It also makes the classes too tightly coupled as Cyclist now knows that a bike has a gear and a speedometer (indicated by the 'trainwreck', breaking the 'Law of Demeter').